# How can I remove Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, uninstall

When I turn on my computer there is no boot menu to chose Windows XP or Ubuntu I don't know why. I can't access Windows XP and this Ubuntu 11.04 is slow on my computer & I don't want it. In Windows XP there is no in add/remove programs entry for Ubuntu, and my local disk where is installed Ubuntu is now smaller. I cannot recover that free space and I cannot delete that partition, so I need help.

Comment: Please revise your question. This is so hard to read that I can't edit it to make more coherent.

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell us how you installed Ubuntu. If you  did a 'wubi' install 'inside' windows using the exe on the cd, then there Should be a entry for ubuntu in the add/remove program settings tool in windows.

If you booted a cd and did a normal install, then you would need to delete the ubuntu partitions, and reinstall the windows bootloader.  Then resize or repartition the hard drives to get the space back where windows can use it.

Comment: i put my CD, ubuntu CD in comp & i was restart my comp but the problem is if i delete ubuntu partitions i can't turn on my comp anymore & i do not have windows CD :S can i reinstall windows bootloader without windows CD?

Comment: I have seen links at some windows sites to some legal (as far as i know) windows rescue cd's  supplied by microsoft.  When you deleted ubuntu, your grub loader no longer has the config files to work properly. You must use some sort of windows rescue/recovery method to reinstall the windows bootloader. There is also the super-grub rescue cd that might be able to reinstall the windows bootloader.  http://www.supergrubdisk.org/wiki/UninstallGRUB

Answer (score -1):

Use TestDisk
It has a boot disk option that will re-write the MBR
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download